# How to compare generic type member of generic classin java

Tags: java, generics

I am facing difficulty in writing a generic class in java whose generic members can be compared.

Following is the code snippet I have written, but it is giving me compilation error.

```
public class TestClass <E extends Comparable<E>>{
private E data1;
private E data2;

    public void fun(){
        if(data1 > data2){

        }
    }

}
```

It is giveing me error by saying that compare('>') operations is not valid.
As per my understanding if I am extending Comparable I should be able to this operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java isn't C++, and doesn't have operator overloading.  You need to use [`.compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29), which is provided by the `Comparable` interface.  For example:

```
if(data1.compareTo(data2) > 0){
```

Comment: Thanks ziesemer. One doubt. Instead of `E extends Comparable<E>` if I write `E extends Integer` than `data1 > data2` is working fine. I am assuming that it is allowing `>` operation in this case because it is applicable to integer. Shouldn't the same concept apply while I am extending `Comparable<E>` because `>` operation is allowed on all comparable object.

Comment: @shantanu - that's just it - the '<' and '>' operators are not useable with Comparable, or any other non-primitive types (int, short, etc.) for that matter.  The only reason why it even works with `Integer` (non-primitive) is because of Java 5's auto-unboxing, which first converts the `Integer` to an `int` to do the comparison.  (Otherwise, you'd have to use `Integer.compareTo(Integer anotherInteger)`, just as with the above.)